# Is it possible to detect the USB-debugging on android devices?

Tags: android, debugging, usb

in my app i need a way to detect if the android-device runs in usb-debugging mode.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

thanx in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the following to get whether or not the ADB is enabled.

```
int adb = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),  Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
```

If it is enabled, `adb == 1`, otherwise `adb == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

On my Android 2.3 device it is possible to detect the usb debugging mode by scanning the complete process list (`ps -s`) for the process `/sbin/adbd`.

If this process is present USB debugging is enabled.

Comment: does this work without special permissions like android.permission.GET_TASKS ?

Comment: This will not work on Android Nougat. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205565

Comment: I could see at least the process `shell` when following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732749/how-to-make-adb-shell-ps-list-all-processes-in-android-o) in Pie. Not sure though if ***p***_rocess_ ***s***_tatus_ is also going to be available from inside apps, or if instead it is just adb-specific (and so being kind of redundant for the purpose).

Comment: @mirh since about Android 8 or 9 apps do not see any other processes than their own.

Comment: I see, I just tested instead with "terminal emulator" and there's basically nothing to see anymore. Though I still wonder if the extended permissions of [Shizuku](https://www.xda-developers.com/implementing-shizuku/) (which is the second best thing after rooting) couldn't still let you see something more.