# How to make adb shell ps list all processes in Android O?

Tags: android, adb, ps, usb-debugging, android-8.0-oreo

`adb shell ps` not working in O android release

`adb shell ps` command in Android O release is listing only `ps` process information, but it is not listing all the processes information of all the process like it used to do it in earlier android releases

what is the command to list all the processes information in android O release?

Comment: can you please let me know what is unclear in this?

Comment: Can you please let me know why the downvote is for?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`adb shell ps -A` is listing all processes in android-8.0-O release.

I think Google has upgraded `ps` binary in this release.

Comment: What's the output your getting

Comment: I am getting null string when i am reading  after executing process

Comment: Got your code from another company question, let me try and update

Comment: Hi @be_good_do_good I am only getting list of process by system not getting any root process so any solution for that ? I am applying this command progrmatically and I am getting process which are aquired by same user not from root or system. Any solution for this ?

Comment: As long as process is running, it will be listed irrespective of user. Are you sure your processes is still running?

Comment: Yes @be_good_do_good process is running. I am sure on that because I am running that system process manually. When I am running the same command in windows it gives me process data of system, root and user but when I am progrmatically firing same command in device it gives me data of user only. This is how I am running the commandd in android.
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps");

Comment: @be_good_do_good when I run it via machine terminal, it lists all processes but, when I run it in the Android app code, it only lists the app process and ps process!

Answer (score 24):

Answer is: `ps -A`

But, there are so many new options in `ps`. Try running `ps --help`

```
generic_x86:/ $ ps --help
usage: ps [-AadefLlnwZ] [-gG GROUP,] [-k FIELD,] [-o FIELD,] [-p PID,] [-t TTY,] [-uU USER,]

List processes.

Which processes to show (selections may be comma separated lists):

-A  All processes

-a  Processes with terminals that aren't session leaders

-d  All processes that aren't session leaders

-e  Same as -A

-g  Belonging to GROUPs

-G  Belonging to real GROUPs (before sgid)

-p  PIDs (--pid)

-P  Parent PIDs (--ppid)

-s  In session IDs

-t  Attached to selected TTYs

-T  Show threads

-u  Owned by USERs

-U  Owned by real USERs (before suid)

Output modifiers:

-k  Sort FIELDs in +increasing or -decreasting order (--sort)

-M  Measure field widths (expanding as necessary)

-n  Show numeric USER and GROUP

-w  Wide output (don't truncate fields)

Which FIELDs to show. (Default = -o PID,TTY,TIME,CMD)

-f  Full listing (-o USER:12=UID,PID,PPID,C,STIME,TTY,TIME,ARGS=CMD)

-l  Long listing (-o F,S,UID,PID,PPID,C,PRI,NI,ADDR,SZ,WCHAN,TTY,TIME,CMD)

-o  Output FIELDs instead of defaults, each with optional :size and =title

-O  Add FIELDS to defaults

-Z  Include LABEL
```